# How can I stop js script from running on mobile?

Tags: javascript, theming

I need some help with a Zen subtheme using responsive-sidebars.css
I have some javascript that I only want to run if the screen is bigger than 480px.
The javascript is:

```
(function ($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         $('#selllink').trigger("click");
       });
    })
```

I am not sure how I would restrict this.
Many Thanks
Julie

Answer (score 1):

You can deetect the screen size in Vanilla JS or jQuery. In jQuery you can use [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) to get screen size. So you can try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if($(window).width() > 480){
    $('#selllink').trigger("click");
  }
});
```

You could also use [`resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) to check for window resize event.